# Error at installing package Swashbuckle/swagger in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, nuget

I'm following a tutorial for install "Swashbuckle" or Swagger for creating the documentation of a C# Web API.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 for this task, but, when I execute the following command in the NuGet Package Manager Console:

```
Install-Package Swashbuckle
```

I get this error:

> Install-Package : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. At line:1 char:16
>
> - Install-Package <<<<  Swashbuckle
> - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], WebException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

I tried:

- Uninstall and install NuGet Package Manager - it has the sign "This extension is already installed".
- Followed the steps shown [here](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/issues/7705) to enable TLS1/ TLS2 - a few questions and answers in Stack Overflow pointed out that this error was due those changes in TLS...
- Downloaded "nuget.exe" from this URL: `https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/latest/nuget.exe` and use this program for download the package, but, it didn't get installed in the project, but in the *Downloads* folder instead - for this, I don't think the problem is the company proxy I'm working on...
- I followed the steps mentioned [here](http://skolima.blogspot.com/2012/07/nuget-proxy-settings.html) for setting the proxy settings in the "nuget.config" file, but, the results are the same.
- Use "https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" and "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" as packages sources, but, the first URL one shows the error:

  > The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send

  and the second URL just keeps executing.
- Close and re-open all instances of Visual Studio (2 opened instances).

Are there any more options to install NuGet packages in the solution I'm working on?

Comment: Please try to run `[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol=[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol-bOR [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12` under `Package Manager Console` and then install the package again.

Comment: Please let us know if it helps or not.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT thank you for your answer. I tried and it's downloading certain dll's - it seems my project has some dependency issues `Successfully installed 'WebActivatorEx 2.0.6'.` and it's downloading and installing such dll's. Please post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it. Thank you.

Comment: Sure. Glad to know that this works for you. And I have added it as an answer and you can check it:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Error at installiing package Swashbuckle/swagger in Visual Studio 2012

For your issue, since old VS2012 used `TLS 1.0` and the latest nuget cli does not support it. You should use TLS `1.2`.

**Solution**

Please run

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol=[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol-bOR [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

under **Package Manager Console**(under **TOOLS**-->**Nuget Package Manager**)